# Phalcon Installation on Macbook MacOs Catalina

Tags: installation, phalcon

I tried installing phalcon with homebrew this error comes occurring. How can I install PSR on mac?

[image: 1]

Comment: please do not share the error as an image, it is so hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
pecl install psr
```

pecl is for downloading php extensions, and if I am not mistaken psr is a php extension.
check this [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/psr)